# Как добавить методы в класс, автоматически сгенерированный Entity Framework'ом?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Entity Framework Core сгенерировал классы сущностей для таблиц базы данных MS SQL. Есть класс Employees для таблицы с сотрудниками. С экземплярами этого класса я работаю в своей программе и перед сохранением их в БД хочу провести валидацию, условно говоря, как-то так:

```cs
var emp = new Employees();
emp.LastName = "JenkinsOhNoThereIsSomeMistake";
if (emp.IsValid())
    // код сохранения
```

На данный момент я делаю через методы расширения:

```cs
public static class EmployeeValidator
{
    ...
    public static bool IsValid(this Employees emp)
    {
        ...
```

Является ли такой подход нормальной практикой или надо как-то по-другому?

Поскольку автосгенерированные классы сущностей - partial, я еще думал создать аналогичные классы, тоже partial, и туда дописать все что нужно. Но они должны быть в том же неймспейсе => их нужно класть в ту же папку, а Visual Studio не позволяет это сделать.

Comment: *должны быть в том же неймспейсе => их нужно класть в ту же папку* — по идее — нет, неймспейс и папка могут отличаться

Comment: С другой стороны, должна ли сущность уметь себя валидировать или это не ее обязанность? Можно создать семейство валидаторов, получать нужный валидатор при необходимости и просить его валидировать вашу сущность. Типа `var validator = _validatorsFactory.Get<Employees>(); validator.Validate(emp);`

Comment: Я добавил папку в проект, создал в ней класс и вручную исправил неймспейс на тот, где лежат EF-классы. После ребилдинга действительно заработало. Хотя вроде я и раньше так пытался.

Касаемо валидации сущностью самой себя, я пишу Wpf программу, у меня есть образец (демка Josh Smith по MVVM) и он там реализует на сущности IDataErrorInfo, а потом за счет этого биндит ошибки к граф. интерфейсу, поэтому я тоже так начал делать. Может есть и другой способ конечно, но я пока только такой нашел.

Comment: Ах, ну раз это WPF, я рекомендую вам завести отдельные классы для VM и для EF. Иначе намучаетесь.

Comment: А у меня отдельные как раз. Есть EmployeeViewModel, там свойства для заполнения и команда Сохранить. Когда эта VM создается, в нее я передаю новый экземпляр EF'овского Employees и dbcontext и сохраняю их в приватные поля VM (_emp и _context). Соответственно, в геттерах и сеттерах свойств VM я использую объект _emp и его реальные поля. Таким образом с помощью биндинга данные из графических элементов попадают сразу в _emp и я его могу сохранить.